# Is there a way to change CSS styles of part of input value?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-5

So I am creating a form with React.js and a particular input has to match the label that is written above it like so:

[image]

And if there is a typo then the text becomes red:

[image]

Right now the entire input value becomes red which is not what I want.
Is there a way to target only the typo characters inside the input value and change their css styles so only those characters become red?

`Line.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Line(props){
//State for checking if theres error in the input.
//false >>> no error
//true  >>> has error
let [err, setErr] = useState(false);
let [done, setDone] = useState(false);
//Executes every keystroke
function inputHandler(event){
    const input = event.target.value;

    //console.log(x.slice(-1));
    //console.log(x.length);

    //Compares every char of input to the label
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        //Error was found in this iteration
        //Set error font color
        if(input[i] !== props.label[i]){
            console.log(input[i] + " did not match " + props.label[i])
            setErr(true);
            return;
        }
        //After last iteration no error was found
        //Set font to normal
        if(i === (input.length-1)){
            setErr(false);
        }
      }
    //if there is no error and I have typed everything from label
    //Set success colour
    if(input.length === props.label.length && !err){
        setDone(true);
    } else {setDone(false)}
}

return <div className="container-fluid form-group d-flex flex-column justify-content-center 
text-center">
    <label className="form-control-plaintext">{props.label}</label>
    <input id='demo' type='text' className={`form-control ${err ? 'text-danger' : null} ${done 
? 'text-success' : null}`} onChange={inputHandler} maxLength={props.label.length}/>
</div>
}

export default Line;
```

You have to include the bootstrap link and scripts in index.html for the classes to work:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: You are better off using content editable div for this purpose instead of input . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

AFAIK this is not possible to do with input tag

Comment: That is not a bad idea actually

Comment: No, you can't style part of an `input` value. `contentdeitble` is the way to go.

Comment: I was going to suggest content-editable div. But honestly, you could just use the `pattern` attribute of input. This won't make the mistake in a different color, but it will make the input red and explain the necessary pattern to the user

Answer (score 1):

You can use editable div to create an input component and then logically handle your states for various types. This is almost the same as rich text editor.

Reference - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp